# Vim: Search for patterns and add text to end of each line where it occurs

Tags: search, vim, replace

I would like to search for a pattern in vim, and on each line where it occurs, add text to the end of the line. For example, if the search pattern is `print(` and the text to add is `)`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('Pausing 30 seconds...'
print("That's not a valid year!"
```

should become

```
from __future import print_function
print('Pausing 30 seconds...')
print("That's not a valid year!")
```

Comment: also: cursor on "print", hit `*A)` and `n.` to repeat ad nauseam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Globally append to line with matching term in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216625/globally-append-to-line-with-matching-term-in-vim)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this command should do it for you:

```
:g/print(/norm! A)
```

what it does:

```
:g/print(/   "find all lines matching the regex
norm! A)     "do norm command, append a ")" at the end of the matched line.
```

you may want to check

```
:h :g
```

for details.

Answer (score 1):

To add text to the end of a line that begins with a certain string, try:

```
:g/^print(/s/$/)
```

See: [Power of g - Examples](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g#Examples) for further explanation.